# python dictionaries are hashmaps of pointers to...what?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-internals

I know that in python, dictionaries are implemented by hashing the keys and storing pointers (to the key-value pairs) in an array, the index being determined by the hash.

But how are the key-value pairs themselves stored? Are they stored together (ie, in contiguous spots in memory)? Are they stored as a tuple or array of pointers, one pointing to the key and one to the value? Or is it something else entirely?

Googling has turned up lots of explanations about hashing and open addressing and the like, but nothing addressing this question.

Comment: Note that this is implementation specific, and there is more than one implementation of Python.  I can think of CPython, PyPy, IronPython and Jython.  I don't know, but I would expect IronPython and Jython to use .Net/Java Map. to implement a dictionary.

Comment: There is a great talk about the various versions of Python dictionaries by Raymond Hetttinger here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking there is a function, let's call it `F`, which calculates an index, `F(h)`, in an array of values.  So the values are stored as an array and they are looked up as `F(h)`.  The reason it's "roughly speaking", is that hashes are computed differently for different objects.  For example, for pointers, it's `p>>3`; while for strings, hashes are digests of all the bytes of a string.

If you want to look at the C code, search for `lookdict_index` or just look at the dictobject.c file in CPython's source code.  It's pretty readable if you are used to reading C code.

**Edit 1:**
From the comment in Python 3.6.1's Include/dictobject.h:

```
/* If ma_values is NULL, the table is "combined": keys and values
   are stored in ma_keys.

   If ma_values is not NULL, the table is splitted:
   keys are stored in ma_keys and values are stored in ma_values */
```

And an explanation from dictobject.:

```
/*
The DictObject can be in one of two forms.

Either:
  A combined table:
    ma_values == NULL, dk_refcnt == 1.
    Values are stored in the me_value field of the PyDictKeysObject.
Or:
  A split table:
    ma_values != NULL, dk_refcnt >= 1
    Values are stored in the ma_values array.
    Only string (unicode) keys are allowed.
    All dicts sharing same key must have same insertion order.
....
*/
```

The values are either stored as an array of strings which follows an array of "key objects". or each value's pointer is stored in the `me_value` of `PyDictKeyEntry`.  The keys are stored in `me_key` fields of `PyDictKeyEntry`.  The array of keys is really an array of `PyDictKeyEntry` structs.

Just as a reference, `PyDictKeyEntry` is defined as:

```
   typedef struct {
       /* Cached hash code of me_key. */
       Py_hash_t me_hash;
       PyObject *me_key;
       PyObject *me_value; /*This field is only meaningful for combined tables*/
   } PyDictKeyEntry;
```

Relevant files to look at: Objects/dict-common.h, Objects/dictobject.c, and Include/dictobject.h in Python's source code.

Objects/dictobject.c has an extensive write up in the comments in the beginning of the file explaining the whole scheme and historical background.

Comment: Yes, I understand about hash functions. That's how python knows where in the array to stick the pointer to the key-value pair. But how is the key-value pair itself stored? (I guess my question is really because it's a key-value _pair_. In the case of a set, I assume the pointer just points to the item. But because there's a key _and_ a value, I wondering how they're stored.)... Or are you saying there's a _second_ array, to store pointers to values, and the original array stores pointers to keys (the correspondence being made via matching indices)?

Comment: @Katie, I added more details after the "Edit 1".  If it's still unclear or TL;DR, please, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @dmitry, I'll check it out!